# How can I COPY files only if in production with Dockerfile?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I was recently planning to deploy my app to server using docker. I have successfully setup my development environment using docker and tangled with docker-compose for a while.

My `Dockerfile` looks like this:

```
FROM alpine

# ...

COPY . /app
```

and the `docker-compose.yml` file looks like this:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  host:
    build:
      dockerfile: .docker/Dockerfile
      context: .
    volumes: 
      - .:/app
# ...
```

Now the question is:

If I issue command `docker-compose up -d`, docker will first copy all my files into the image /app directory **(this is desirable for production)**, and then mount my project into container /app **(for development)** overriding the work for production.

What if my project has 1 GB of files, do I have to waste that time for waiting docker copying all those files for nothing?

Is there a way which I can instruct docker not to copy all those files if it was built for development? Or do I really have to make multiple Dockerfiles for multiple scenarios like testing/staging?

What if where's a very long and complex building process in the `Dockerfile`, changing a bit in say `Dockerdevelopmentfile` would cause a disaster in production if I forgot to change it in `Dockerproductionfile`.

What if I need to build 5 to 10 images for my project and even hundreds of images for a company for multiple project?

I don't think that's practical.

Please do forgive my naiveness.
I really appreciate for some advices.

Comment: best practice is to use separated dockerfiles for each environment

Comment: Best practice is to run the same single image for production and non-production setups.  When would you want these images to be different, and especially as radically different as the question suggests?

Comment: @DavidMaze Maybe like having some debugging tools in dev mode? Maybe more secure setup for production? I'm not sure. Maybe I should try bundling everything together. Thanks.

Comment: @EfratLevitan That's just sad.

Comment: Tell some more what type of application you are talking about? 1gb looks quite a lot. "do I have to waste that time for waiting docker copying all those files for nothing?" What do you mean "for nothing"? If you want to have it in your image you need to build it each time you want to update the image. And you can use different docker-compose.yml files for dev and prod. You don't need the binding on the prod.

Comment: @Ovsyanka It's just some web app, having a lot of dependencies and photos, videos etc. With "for nothing" I mean docker copied my project first, and then override it with volume binding, it's redundant for development. So I wonder if I could avoid the copy in dev mode.

Comment: @EricYoung Are all that photos and videos the part of the site or they are "user data"? About copying. I still not understand the problem. When do you need to rebuild the images for development? In my opinion it should be rarely needed - when you change image configuration (Dockerfile itself or installed software). Are you talking about this case or some another?

Comment: @Ovsyanka Some are user generated content, but I figured it out now. The question is invalid. Because it's true that I don't really have to rebuild the image for development just like you said, I'm just new to docker, I don't really know the workflow. I'm gonna edit the question to clear things up. Thank you so much for your patience and help.

Comment: @EricYoung, it is great =) I would suggest you right away to store all your dynamic (user) data in the docker volumes instead of container.